# How to group library jars under WEB-INF/lib in a web application using eclipse ide

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, jakarta-ee, struts2

until now am copying all of my dependency jars to WEB-INF/lib folder for web applications developing in eclipse, its complicated to identify those jars when it is more numbers. for example in an application with struts and hibernate frame works i am copying all jars of struts (more than 60 jars) and of hibernate (more than 15) directly to lib folder.

Question is :  How i could group those jars as libraries under WEB-INF/lib folder ?

Comment: why you don't use maven to handle all such dependencies for you?

Comment: Or Ant (with [Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) if you want Maven's dependency management). Don't rely on the IDE for such things...it's really easy to set up something that can be run from the IDE or the command line.

Comment: thanks, i am not familiar with maven , am trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just to keep an overview of all your libraries, you could consider organising them into [User Libraries](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/buildpath/ref-preferences-user-libraries.htm).

Another option (not for everyone) would be to have separate projects for each set of libraries (of course they'd need to export those and be included in dependent projects).

Comment: thanks, i already tried that, i organized two user libs one for Hibernate and for Struts,  but i can't refer struts classe in web modules like jsp, also it is not able to attach as a part of war to deploy

Comment: Do you mean you can't refer to classes in your user libraries from your JSPs? You should be able to... but if you're looking for a solution outside of Eclipse, I'd go with Maven as @Umesh said.